# I need to change date format from "xx time ago" like: a year ago, 1 week ago to "%Y/%m/%d"

Tags: r, date

I have data collected from the internet. The date column format is like "1 month ago" "2 years ago" "4 days ago", and I need to change this format.

I tried this:

```
googleR$`Date/Time` <- as.Date.character(googleR$`Date/Time`, 
                                         format = format(googleR$`Date/Time`), 
                                         tryFormats = c("%d/%m/%Y"))
```

but it gave me today's date only for all the records

also I tried many other things but the same error appears

> "character string is not in a standard unambiguous format"

here is the data i am trying to convert:

```
format.factor(googleR$`Date/Time`)
 [1] "7 months ago " "2 months ago " "a week ago   " "2 years ago  " "2 years ago  " "5 months ago " "10 months ago"
 [8] "2 years ago  " "4 years ago  " "2 years ago  " "2 years ago  " "11 months ago" "3 years ago  " "3 years ago  "
[15] "2 years ago  " "2 years ago  " "10 months ago" "10 months ago" "a year ago   " "a year ago   " "2 years ago  "
[22] "2 years ago  " "2 years ago  " "2 years ago  " "2 years ago  " "2 years ago  " "3 years ago  " "4 years ago  "
[29] "4 years ago  " "a week ago   " "a week ago   " "2 weeks ago  " "a month ago  " "2 months ago " "5 months ago "
[36] "7 months ago " "7 months ago " "8 months ago " "10 months ago" "10 months ago" "a year ago   " "a year ago   "
[43] "a year ago   " "a year ago   " "a year ago   " "a year ago   " "a year ago   " "2 years ago  " "2 years ago  "
[50] "2 years ago  " "4 years ago  " "6 years ago  "
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sub` to remove "ago" from each element, then use `lubridate`'s `add_with_rollback` as follows

```
library(lubridate)
add_with_rollback(Sys.time(), - as.period(sub("\\s+ago", "", x)))
```

Result

```
"2019-02-28 18:13:18 CET"  "2017-03-31 18:13:18 CEST" "2019-03-27 18:13:18 CET"
```

**data**

```
x <- c("1 month ago", "2 years ago", "4 days ago")
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't even know about "add_with_rollback"!

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to start by using regular expressions to figure out what type of time interval you've got and then go from there. I like the stringr package for that. For example, if IN is your input string and OUT is your desired output, you could say

```
 if(str_detect(IN, "day")){OUT <- as.numeric(str_extract(IN, "^[0-9]*"))}
```

Now, you've got the number of days ago and you can do something like

```
 Sys.Date() - OUT
```

to get the date. You can then do basically the same thing for months and years. This is inevitably going to be approximate since not all months have the same number of days, for example, but it sounds like your input data aren't super precise anyway.